# Can registers be referenced in Atmel Studio (ATtiny2313)?

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

From what I've seen so far, it's legal to use a pointer to a register but there was nothing about references.

Is something like that legal?

```
byte &registers[4] = {DDRA, DDRB, DDRC, DDRD};
```

I am using Atmel Studio 7.0

Comment: Check the type of the register expressions. Something like `volatile uint8_t* myReg = &DDRA`  should work.

Comment: @JimmyB yes that will work. but the point is i need a reference eg. uint8_t &myReg = DDRA

Comment: ["There shall be no ... arrays of references"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)#ISO_definition)